# Polymer how to bind paper-input value to iron-ajax

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

The following is my page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>GP and Practice search</title>   <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/home.css"/>
    <!-- google fonts definitions -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <dom-module id="page-scafolding">
        <template>
            <paper-drawer-panel elevation="1">
                <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
                    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
                        <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                        <span class="flex"></span>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler" id="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
                        <input type="text" id="searchText" hidden$="{{hideSearch}}" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event);" />
                        <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name ident">Search</div>
                    </paper-toolbar>
                    <paper-material elevation="1" class="contentContainer" >
                        <div id="Content" >
                            <span>
                                <paper-input id="searchCriteria" 
                                             class="searchBox" 
                                             label="Code or name of the GP or Practice you are looking for?"  />
                            </span>
                            <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px;">
                                <paper-button tabindex="0" raised="true" class="colorful" on-click="searchPractice">Search for Practice</paper-button>
                                <paper-button tabindex="0" raised="true" class="colorful" on-click="searchPractice">Search for GP</paper-button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="SearchResult">
                                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
                                    <p><span>{{item.Name}}</span> (<span>{{item.PracticeCode}}</span>)</p>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </paper-material>
                    <iron-ajax id="GPSearch"
                               url="/GPPractices.ashx"
                               handle-as="json"
                               last-response="{{data}}"
                               params='{{ajaxParams}}'
                               handleerror="handleError">

                    </iron-ajax>
                </paper-header-panel>
            </paper-drawer-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "page-scafolding",
                ready: function () {
                    this.hideSearch = true;
                    this.$.searchText.keyup(function (e) {
                        alert('off to search for something!');
                    });
                },
                ajaxParams: {
                    type: String,
                    computed: 'buildSearchRequest();'
                },
                buildSearchRequest: function () {
                    return {
                        Command: 'Search',
                        Criteria: this.$.searchCriteria
                    }
                },
                srchandler: function () {
                    // search for contents of search box is showing, otherwise show it.
                    if (!this.hideSearch)
                    {
                        alert('off to search for something!');
                    }
                    else {
                        this.hideSearch = !this.hideSearch;
                        if (!this.hideSearch) {
                            this.$.searchText.focus();
                        }
                    }
                },
                searchPractice: function () {
                    try {           
                        this.$.GPSearch.generateRequest();
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert("Whoops! " + e.message);
                    }

                },
                handleError: function (request, error) {
                    alert('Whoops! ' + error);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>

    <page-scafolding />
</body>
</html>
```

I have got the ajax call being made and a call to GPPractices.ashx is being made. What I am trying to do is pass two parameters to this page. One is Command and has the value 'search', the other parameter is whatever is input into the paperInput called searchCriteria.

The trouble is instead of getting two parameters Command and Criteria. I am getting an empty QueryString and it does not look like buildSearchRequest is ever called.

So how can I get it so that if I type say 'abba' into the paper-input the query string should be

```
Command=search&criteria=abba
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Not sure if this is officially the best way, but by changing the code of the searchPractice function to the following - the correct QueryString is sent and the search works.

```
            searchPractice: function () {
                try {
                    this.$.GPSearch.params = {
                        Command: 'Search',
                        Criteria: this.$.searchCriteria.value
                    };
                    this.$.GPSearch.generateRequest();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert("Whoops! " + e.message);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 8):

I put a simplified working version of your code below. Here are some notes:

1. This declaration

   ```
   ajaxParams: {
     type: String,
     computed: 'buildSearchRequest();'
   },
   ```

   is a property definition and has to go inside `properties` object.
2. Callback values such as

   ```
   computed: 'buildSearchRequest();'
   ```

   *look like functions* but they aren't actual code, and need no trailing `;`
3. Your *computed* function needs to have an argument to tell it when to recompute. I modified it to look like this:

   ```
   computed: 'buildSearchRequest(searchCriteria)'
   ```

   and I bound `searchCriteria` to the input `value`.
4. Event handlers in Polymer code use `on-` notation, so

   ```
   onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event);"
   ```

   should be

   ```
   on-keypress="handleKeyPress"
   ```
5. iron-ajax error notification is via event called `error`, so

   ```
   handleerror="handleError"
   ```

   should be

   ```
   on-error="handleError"
   ```
6. I added the `stringify` bit and the output of the params just so you could see it calculating as you type, it's not necessary for your use case.
7. Only a tiny handful of elements are *void* in HTML (need no closing tag). You should avoid doing `<tag-name/>` because it will cause trouble eventually.

Live: http://jsbin.com/sorowi/edit?html,output

```
    <dom-module id="page-scafolding">
      <template>

        <paper-input 
          label="Code or name of the GP or Practice you are looking for?" 
          value="{{searchCriteria}}">
        </paper-input>

        <br>

        <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px;">
          <paper-button tabindex="0" raised="true" style="background-color: lightblue;" on-click="searchPractice">Search for Practice</paper-button>
        </div>

        <iron-ajax id="GPSearch"
                   url="/GPPractices.ashx"
                   handle-as="json"
                   last-response="{{data}}"
                   params="{{ajaxParams}}"
                   on-error="handleError">   
        </iron-ajax>

        <br><br>
        ajaxParams: <span>{{stringify(ajaxParams)}}</span>

        <div id="SearchResult">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <p><span>{{item.Name}}</span> (<span>{{item.PracticeCode}}</span>)</p>
          </template>
        </div>

      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({

          is: "page-scafolding",

          properties: {
            ajaxParams: {
              type: String,
              computed: 'buildSearchRequest(searchCriteria)'
            }
          },

          stringify: JSON.stringify, 

          buildSearchRequest: function (criteria) {
            return {
              Command: 'Search',
              Criteria: criteria
            };
          },

          searchPractice: function () {
            this.$.GPSearch.generateRequest();
          },

          handleError: function(e) {
            alert('Whoops! ' + e.detail);
          }

        });
      </script>
  </dom-module>
```

HTH

Comment: This gotta be one of the best answers in SO for beginners to Polymer! +1 for listing the gotchas.